# Laravel's skip() function only works on the first query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

URL: www.example.com/1 (where 1 is id=1 from the table)

I have a button that allows users to go to the next or previous records if possible. (www.example.com/2):

```
$next = Video::where('id', '>', $id)->min('id');
```

Now, when I want users to jump 10 records I tried:

```
Video::where('id', '>=', $id)->skip(10)->first();
```

I do get the right record (lets say it jumps from 1 to 11). However, when I go to the next record (www.example.com/2) I will get the exact same result for skip() function (11) and even further down on record 3 it still does not update?

I did check that $id that goes into the skip() query is being changed. Why might this function not update?

p.s.:
My controller:

```
public function show ($id){
$next = Video::where('id', '>', $id)->min('id');
$previous = Video::where('id', '<', $id)->max('id');
$skip = Video::where('id', '>=', $id)->skip(10)->first();

return view('page',[
'next' =>  $next,
'prev' => $prev,
'skip' => $skip,
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `$skip = Video::where('id', '>=', $id)->get($id + 10);` I am not sure if it will work and if get() will accept a parameter, but give it a try.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the next button ?

Comment: @Chris The problem with that method is that my ids are not all sequential. Hence, it might skip fewer than wanted records and also there might not be such an id. I think skip() overcomes that problem.

Comment: @Maraboc `<a href="{{ URL::to( '/' . $next ) }}"><button class="btn btn-danger next" name="next">Next</button></a>`

Comment: My Route: `Route::get('/{id}', 'HomeController@show');`

Comment: And for the skip button code ?

Comment: @ Maraboc I am just testing it. I just did `<p>{{$skip->id}}</p>` to see what it would output and its always the same

Comment: are you testing with clicking on the button or with modification on url ?
 because if with the url maybe the given value of `id` not even passes the next record, for example if you have ids in your table like this 1, 5, 9, 15 ... if you give the values 1, 2, 3 or 4 you will get the same result but if you give 5 then you will get the wanted result !!

Comment: @Maraboc I tested both, same thing. Hmmm, I don't know if its my application or if its the skip function in general?

Comment: I tested the same logic with users and it's just fine in my local machine !!
 try to `dump` next and prev and `{{$skip->id}}` and compare the results with your database !

Comment: @Maraboc I see, I will try to debug this. Something is messed up here. Thanx a bunch for your help, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The `first` method always returns first record and will respect `where` clause and ignore `skip` method.

Proposed solution for that:

```
$collection = YourModel::where(SOMETHING HERE)->skip(10)->take(1)->get();
```

Now we have collection. We can access first element in different ways:

```
$item = $collection[0]; // array-like syntax
$item = $collection->first(); // standard collection method
```